# How to bind X-Axis of xamdatachart and XamNumericRangeSlider in wpf (infragistics)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, slider, infragistics, xamdatachart

Friends,

I have XamDataChart with Line series and a XamNumericRangeSlider below that chart. This slider bar should represent x-axis of above chart, and i want to get the position of Tick from slider every time user slides and then highlight ( or some action ) the corresponding point in the chart. so is there any way to bind x axis and slider ranges ? or any better way to handle it ? because i want this functionality ( usercontrol ) to be dynamic.

Please guide me.  Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Ravi.